# SQL: order values in a partition based on previous (ordered) partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

Scratching my head to solve below ordering problem in SQL (Teradata and BigQuery).

My starting point is as per below:

| ts | state |
| --- | --- |
| ts1 | NY |
| ts1 | AL |
| ts2 | CA |
| ts2 | NY |
| ts3 | CA |
| ts4 | CA |
| ts5 | FL |
| ts5 | CA |
| ts6 | NY |
| ts6 | FL |

I want to partition by timestamp (`ts`) but also (re)order the states within the partition window so that the first `state` value matches the last `state` in the previous window.

**Desired order (if know first state is `AL`):**

| ts | state |
| --- | --- |
| ts1 | AL |
| ts1 | NY |
| ts2 | NY |
| ts2 | CA |
| ts3 | CA |
| ts4 | CA |
| ts5 | CA |
| ts5 | FL |
| ts6 | FL |
| ts6 | NY |

So I need to generate the proper index within a partition to use `PARTITION BY ts ORDER BY idx`.

**Constraints**:

1. each partition is always 1 or 2 rows
2. the very first state value (first row in first partition) is known upfront (and is variable)

**What I have tried before:**

```
-- go 1 or 2 row(s) up to get last row of previous ts. If same state, then 1 (right order) else 2
case when state=(
    -- check if first or 2nd row    
    case when row_number() over (partition by ts order by 1)  = 1
        -- read the state of the last row of previous partition
        then lag(state) over (order by ts, state) 
        else lag(state, 2) over (order by ts, state) end
        )
    then 1 else 2 end as idx
```

This works only for one pair and assumes previous partition has the right order already.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Note this is part of a sql `VIEW` so no scripting possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having below constraints:

1. each partition is always 1 or 2 rows
2. the very first state value (first row in first partition) is known upfront (and is variable)

... consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
WITH RECURSIVE TEMP AS (
  SELECT ts, state, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ts) grp
  FROM your_table ORDER BY grp 
), result AS (
  SELECT ts, state, grp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IF(state='AL', '_', state) DESC) pos, 1 i
  FROM TEMP WHERE grp = 1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ts, t.state, t.grp,IF(r.state = t.state, 1, 2) pos,  i + 1 AS i
  FROM TEMP T 
  JOIN result r 
  ON r.grp + 1 = t.grp 
)
SELECT ts, state --, grp, min(pos) pos 
FROM result
GROUP BY ts, state, grp
ORDER BY grp,  MIN(pos)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Had to adjust for Teradata but recursive cte is/was the way to go ! Thx

Answer (score -1):

We have to use a combination of window functions and a self-join to fulfill the two constraints.

1. each partition is always 1 or 2 rows
2. the very first state value (first row in first partition) is known upfront (and is variable)

once check with the below possibility

```
WITH ord_state AS (
  SELECT
    ts,
    state,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ts ORDER BY state) AS rn
  FROM
    table_name
),
prev_state AS (
  SELECT
    ts,
    state,
    LAG(state) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS prev_last_state
  FROM
    ord_state
),
desired_order AS (
  SELECT
    o.ts,
    o.state
  FROM
    ord_state o
    LEFT JOIN prev_state p ON o.ts = p.ts
  ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN o.rn = 1 THEN p.prev_last_state ELSE NULL END,
    o.ts,
    o.state
)
SELECT ts, state FROM desired_order;
```

The query will get the desired output based on the provided dataset.
[google-bigquery](/questions/tagged/google-bigquery)[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)[teradata](/questions/tagged/teradata)

Comment: Doesn't work as it renders dupes. Not sure if this was tested.